# Licence Agreement text not showing during installation using VS setup

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I've added a Licence Agreement dialog box to the setup project and included the license file in .rtf format but the text is not showing in the installation using VS setup. what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The typical issue is that the RTF file is too "modern" for the old-style control that is used in the MSI dialog. It usually works if you open and save the RTF file with Wordpad because that's equally basic. You didn't say how you created the RTF file in the first place, so I assume it is in fact a valid but new RTF file.

Comment: Can you provide any additional details about what it means to be "too modern"?  I tried your advice, and am still experiencing the same problem as OP.